# perl regular expression replace but changed to number

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like

```
 /translation="MNVTRLYFRVAGTKQLARYVHKYAAYSSTSFQKKKSHFPSPATL                     DHPDAGEDAFINLRNENYILNAVFDGVGGWANVGIDPSIFSWGLVREIKKVFNNSDEF                     QPSPLTLLSKAYAALKKSNTVEAGSSTACLTLFNCGNGKLHSLKYVICSLVHKFLLTL                     FQALVTQDFLSLEMVLSIMHHLPKYSNLICHINWLYFLGTIVPLKTLGLKWDKQLCTT                     LKTMTW"                     /translation="MEKEDIEKLFQEVKESLQYSYCPYSNFAVGACVVSDDKNTYIYG                     ANVENASYGNCICAERVAITKAVSMGYTKFMAIGVMSAKGRVTPCGICRQVIREFSKD                     INVYMFHDDGGYDMKTIEELLPDSFGPDDLK"
```

How can i wirte a regular expression to just get all capital letters, like

```
MNVTRLYFRVAGTKQLARYVHKYAAYSSTSFQKKKSHFPSPATLDHPDAGEDAFINLRNENYILNAVFDGVGGWANVGIDPSIFSWGLVREIKKVFNNSDEFQPSPLTLLSKAYAALKKSNTVEAGSSTACLTLFNCGNGKLHSLKYVICSLVHKFLLTLFQALVTQDFLSLEMVLSIMHHLPKYSNLICHINWLYFLGTIVPLKTLGLKWDKQLCTTLKTMTWMEKEDIEKLFQEVKESLQYSYCPYSNFAVGACVVSDDKNTYIYGANVENASYGNCICAERVAITKAVSMGYTKFMAIGVMSAKGRVTPCGICRQVIREFSKDINVYMFHDDGGYDMKTIEELLPDSFGPDDLK
```

I try to use ~s/translation// but it can't work

when i use ~s//translation="// it change to

```
518446744073709551614                     DHPDAGEDAFINLRNENYILNAVFDGVGGWANVGIDPSIFSWGLVREIKKVFNNSDEF                     QPSPLTLLSKAYAALKKSNTVEAGSSTACLTLFNCGNGKLHSLKYVICSLVHKFLLTL                     FQALVTQDFLSLEMVLSIMHHLPKYSNLICHINWLYFLGTIVPLKTLGLKWDKQLCTT                     LKTMTW"18446744073709551614                     ANVENASYGNCICAERVAITKAVSMGYTKFMAIGVMSAKGRVTPCGICRQVIREFSKD                     INVYMFHDDGGYDMKTIEELLPDSFGPDDLK"
```

Update when i use $dna= ~s/[^A-Z]//g;
it shows Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///)
18446744073709551615

Parts of my code

```
  open IN, '</root/Desktop/GeneBank.txt' or die "Cannot open file : $!";;
  while (<IN>) {
  chomp $_;


  if (/^\/\/\n/) { 

  last; 
  } 
  elsif (/"$/&& $in_tran==1) { 
  $in_sequence = 0; 
  $in_tran=0;
  $_= ~s/[^A-Z]//g;
  $dna.=$_;


  }
  elsif ($in_sequence==1) { 
  $_= ~s/[^A-Z]//g;
  $dna .= $_; 

  }
  elsif (/^\s*\Stranslation/) { 
  $in_sequence = 1; 
  $in_tran=1;
  $_= ~s/[^A-Z]//g;
  $dna.=$_;
  #print $line;
  } 

  elsif (/^\s*CDS/) { 

  push(@$annotation, $line); 
  }
  }
  close IN;

  print $dna;
```

but the ~s/[^A-Z]//g change all character to number, it shows like

```
         1844674407370955158018446744073709551594184467440737095515941844674407370955159418446744073709551593184467440737095515801844674407370955159418446744073709551593
```

Comment: Please show us the code you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all the lines:

```
$_= ~s/[^A-Z]//g;
```

with:

```
$_ =~ s/[^A-Z]//g;
```

or, better:

```
s/[^A-Z]+//g;
```

Used like you did, `~` is the bitwise negation. See the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the [binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) that applies a regexp replacement to a variable is `=~` written together — not `= ~` with a space in between, which Perl will parse as an [assignment](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators) (`=`) and a [bitwise negation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators) (`~`).  Thus, if you write:

```
$_= ~s/[^A-Z]//g;
```

Perl will first apply the replacement `s/[^A-Z]//g` to `$_` (by default, since it's not bound to anything else by `=~`) and then take its return value (the number of substitutions made, or an empty string if the number is zero), negate it (bitwise) and assign the result of the bitwise negation back to `$_`, overwriting the result of the replacement.

The way to fix it is simply not to include a space in the middle of operators like `=~`.  Also note that the statements `$_ =~ s/foo/bar/;` and just `s/foo/bar/;` do the exact same thing; you only need the `=~` if you want to apply the replacement to some variable *other* than `$_`.

---

Finally, once you've fixed those issues, you'll still have the problem of how to include a literal slash (`/`) in a regexp.  For that, you have (at least) two solutions:

1. [Quote it by putting a backslash before it](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters), like this:

   ```
   s/\/translation=//;
   ```
2. If you'd rather avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome), use alternative regexp delimiters, e.g.:

   ```
   s!/translation=!!;
   ```

   or:

   ```
   s(/translation=){};
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the capital letters, then replace with '' anything that's not a capital letter in the string:

```
$string =~ s/[^A-Z]//g;
```

Regarding the leading slash, you can escape the `/` with a `\`:

```
$string =~ s/\/translation="//;
```

Alternatively, you can use other delimiters than '/':

```
$string =~ s{/translation="}{};
```

See more at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html and search for "delimiters".

Comment: thanks, but when i use it. it change to number? 518446744073709551614                     DHPDAGEDAFINLRNENYILNA?

Comment: So you don't care about the leading / but just want the letters? I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, but it shows Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///)